# Browser Link JS error on page load

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, browser-link

Using Visual Studio 2013 RTM and Web Essentials I get the following JavaScript error in Chrome on page load.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.main/PhoneIcon.png

My best guess is that it is referring to the following line of html which is near the top of my page.

```
<div class="main/PhoneIcon.png sprite"></div>
```

I'm also not able to edit/modify HTML/CSS using Browser Link.

What do I need to do to fix Browser Link?

Comment: Your class name is invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: That only applies to css selectors. So any selector I would write for that class name would need to be escaped, but the actual html does not need to be escaped. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6732899/2344026

Answer (score 12):

Browser Link tried to create a jQuery selector that would uniquely identify this tag, but it didn't handle the unexpected class name correctly.

You can work around this by adding an ID to the tag. Browser Link would rather use an ID, because it's more likely to be unique. It will ignore the class name if there's a unique ID on the tag.

Or, if you just want Browser Link to get out of the way, you can disable it by unchecking "Enable Browser Link" in the Browser Link menu on the Standard toolbar.

Comment: Where exactly can I find the option to disable browser link? There is no Browser Link menu in the toolbar in my VS.

Comment: On some later versions of VS, the menu is hidden until you open a Web project.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectorsFromCssClasses()` inside Visual Studio itself.  It doesn't escape unusual classnames.

This has nothing to do with Web Essentials; it's a bug in the BrowserLink core.